# If $X= f^{-1}(Y)$, then $f(X) \subseteq Y$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I apologize if this is too basic but I have trouble understanding the following theorem :

**Theorem :** If $X= f^{-1}(Y)$, then $f(X) \subseteq Y$

$f^{-1}(Y) = \{x : x \in S ~And~ f(x) \in Y\}$

With referecnce to the following figure : $f^{-1}$ maps $Y$ to $X$. i.e. $f^{-1}(Y)$ is whole of $X$ which means $f(X)$ should be equal to $Y$ ?

$f(X)$ should be equal to $Y$ ? because when we say $f^{-1}(Y)$ we are recording all those set of points $x \in S$ such that $f(x) \in Y$. Hence,

How did the containment sign come in this relation : $f(X) \subseteq Y$ ?

Where did I go wrong?

Thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: You've asked this before. Not sure what you did with that question, maybe you deleted it. It seems you want to ask not why $X= f^{-1}(Y)\implies f(X)\subseteq Y$, but rather why $X= f^{-1}(Y)\color{red}\not \Rightarrow f(X)= Y$, but this isn't what you're asking at all. And if you think that $X= f^{-1}(Y) \implies f(X)= Y$ holds, then you need to agree that so does $X= f^{-1}(Y)\implies f(X)\subseteq Y$.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957262/if-x-f-1y-then-fx-subseteq-y) is the deleted question.

Comment: @GitGud yeah, I thought I mixed up somethings in the original question and I wasn't able to attach this figure somehow.. That's why I am asking it again.  My question is : Suppose $X \subseteq S$ and $Y  \subseteq T$. Then if $X = f^{-1}(Y)$, then, $f(x) $ should be equal to $Y$ and not be contained in $Y$ because $X$ is already whole of $f^-1(Y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)\in f(X)$, where $x\in X$. We want to show that $f(x)\in Y$.

> Since $X= f^{-1}(Y)$, for this $x$, there exists $y\in Y$, such that $x\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$, and hence $f(x)=y \in Y$.

May it helps!

Comment: @VHP  You are welcome!